# Review before approve edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to know, is it possible to handle the params object at update action to create a new model instead of edit the current model?

What I am trying to do, is to store the edit attempt into a new model for review purpose, then when approved I will implement the update of model using the same params object that were sent in the first place of edit.

But, how would I save the param object to use later when admin approve the edit?
Am I at the right track to approve edit before eventually implement the update?

Comment: Why is the title of this question "Review before approve edit"?

Comment: I am not sure why it has been changed to as it is now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a gem like https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail to solve this issue.

Have a look at this screencast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail

Comment: Thanks, please read discussion of this question's answer, storing params of edit for later usage, what do you think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298747/how-to-serialize-deserialize-params-hash-object/17298848?noredirect=1#comment25086857_17298848

Comment: Yes. But please have a look at the screencast and the documentation. There is not only paper_trail but other tools too. Have a look and pick your choice. No need to reinvent this wheel.