# How to serialize - deserialize params hash object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

how would I do such a thing? I want to be able to store the params object into a string attribute of a model, and be able to deserialize it into params hash object again, how would I do this in ruby? or is there an out of the box solution in rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Active Record can serialize any object in text columns using YAML](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html). To do so, you must specify this with a call to the class method serialize. This makes it possible to store arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects without doing any additional work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

user = User.create(preferences: {background: "black", display: "large"})
User.find(user.id).preferences 
# => {background: "black", display: "large"}
```

Comment: Interesting! do you think I will be able to build a new user from a stored params of :user this way?

Comment: @simo, no reason why not, except good practice. A db record is essentially a serialized, persistent hash. You should need a good reason to lose all of the ActiveRecord goodness before smooshing everything into one field.

Comment: I have a good reason for this, I need to review users update of content before I approve their edits, so I store their edits params, then when I approve it, I update the article using the stored params, instead of models versioning headaches .. what do you think?

Comment: @simo, I'd generally prefer to segregate unapproved users with a boolean attribute like 'approved'. That way you can still do the full range of manipulations and validations on yet-to-be-approved users.

Comment: yea, but my model is a not a user, it has child models belongs to it, I will need to store all objects params to use later ..

Comment: @simo Ah, I would have an `Edit` class that has (at least) a `user_id`, `editable_id`, `editable_type`, `new_values`, and a `is_approved` column. Then you can track the `user` who is making the edits, the `class` and `id` of the record to be edited, and the `new_values` as a serialized hash. Then the `is_approved` can keep track of the approvals. When approved, just use `update_attributes(edit.new_values)` on the record that is getting edited.

Answer (score 0):

Mori's answer is correct, but if your data type in the model is truly a string, it may not fit.  Suggest you use text instead.